# Button field in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to make 2 buttons in my form to select between windows and mac system. What I want is when the form is submitting i should be able to have one name field name="system" with 2 different value on what the user select. Sure i can do it with checkbox or select tag with options but for design i am questioning my self if its possible to do that? thanks in advance

```
     <legend>With what system the data need to be compatible?</legend>
     <button type="button" class="system btn" name="systeme" value="windows">Windows</button>
     <button type="button" class="system btn" name="systeme" value="mac">Mac</button>
```

Comment: Just change the `type` to `submit` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the selected button by adding a class and add a hidden field to the form when submitting it.

```
$(".system").on("click",function(){
    //if the clicked button is not already selected
    if( !$(this).hasClass("selected_system") ){
        //remove the "select" from other selected button
        $(".selected_system").removeClass("selected_system");
        //mark the current button as selected
        $("this").addClass("selected_system");
    }
});
```

now when submitting the form append a hidden input field to the form with the selected button's value

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var sel_button_val = $(".selected_system").val();
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="system" value="'+sel_button_val+'"/>')
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Comment: ill try it out right now and give you feed back if it works or not

Comment: Yes, this would need jQuery library, I have forgotten to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add two button with same name attribute value but, it will not work in backend as you expected.When you read the form fields in backend using name atrribute it return you array of values if you have more than one same name value in form.

You can achive this by updating the value attribute based on button selected before submiting the form.

Hope, This will solve your problem.